# Add log to log file from external .sql executed in sqlplus

Tags: oracle, shell, sqlplus

I have a **test.sh** script with following code:

```
LOG=output.log

sqlplus -s user/pwd@db << EOF > ${LOG}
    WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 9;
    WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE ROLLBACK;

    @testsqlfile
EOF
```

and **testsqlfile.sql** file:

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

EXEC DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TEST');
```

I can't get the log printed in **testsqlfile.sql** to be added in **output.log** file.

If i add SET **serveroutput** and `EXEC DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TEST');` directly in **test.sh** script it works fine. But i can´t add it to **output.log** file from external **testsqlfile.sql** executed as described.

As far as I could find it should work, but it does not.

Thanks.

Comment: Works fine for me. Which shell are you using and how are you executing it? I'd *guess* you're executing `test.sh` from a different directory, and it's either not finding the .sql file, or not finding the version you expect - it'll look in the current working directory, then in ${SQLPATH}` if that is set... Do you get the 'PL/SQL procedure successfully completed' message in the file, or is it empty, or not created at all? Or do you get an OS error message?

Comment: Sorry for late response, was on holidays. 

It is a bash script, executed via putty. Sql file is executed properly, because on a log file i see `1 row inserted` because it is inserting one test record on a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just executed this SQL script directly inside my bash.

```
sqlplus -s user/pwd@db << EOF > ${LOG}
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 9;
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE ROLLBACK;

Direct query
EOF
```